# Is there any way to send money to a second paypal account based on sales made from a first paypal account?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I have an e-commerce where people buy stuff (it is custom made but MAYBE I could replace with woocommerce) .

Each time I sell a specific product, "Product A" I need to send programmatically money to another person using paypal/stripe or any gateway you prefer.

Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can [request access to Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/), which as an API.